# 401 using hybrid relay connections with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I was  just running the sample code from Microsoft to test out hybrid relay connections using node.js

running:

`node listener.js`

producing the following error:

`errorError: unexpected server response (401)`

Here is my code (node listener.js)...

```
    const WebSocket = require('hyco-ws');

 const ns = "hcrelay.servicebus.windows.net";
 const path = "hc1";
 const keyrule = "hc1key";
 const key = "Password@1234";

 var wss = WebSocket.createRelayedServer(
     {
         server : WebSocket.createRelayListenUri(ns, path),
         token: WebSocket.createRelayToken('http://' + ns, keyrule,key)
     }, 
     function (ws) {
         console.log('connection accepted');
         ws.onmessage = function (event) {
             console.log(event.data);
         };
         ws.on('close', function () {
             console.log('connection closed');
         });       
 });

 console.log('listening');

 wss.on('error', function(err) {
     console.log('error' + err);
 });
```

Comment: Are you using the valid key for the SAS rule? The 401 (Unauthorized) status code indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

Comment: When I created It I put in my own key/values that are roughly what you see in the code above... Is there a requirement of what these values should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it worked fine. The key point is that I set `keyrule` equal to the name of Shared access policy and set `key` equal to the primary key of Shared access policy.

```
const WebSocket = require('hyco-ws');

const ns = "hcrelay.servicebus.windows.net";  // Relay namespace
const path = "hc1";                           // Hybrid connection name
const keyrule = "RootManageSharedAccessKey";  // Policy name
const key = "sjSqVUo...";                     // Primary key

var wss = WebSocket.createRelayedServer(
 {
     server : WebSocket.createRelayListenUri(ns, path),
     token: WebSocket.createRelayToken('http://' + ns, keyrule,key)
 }, 
 function (ws) {
     console.log('connection accepted');
     ws.onmessage = function (event) {
         console.log(event.data);
     };
     ws.on('close', function () {
         console.log('connection closed');
     });       
});

console.log('listening');

wss.on('error', function(err) {
 console.log('error' + err);
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response I must have messed up the values for the keyrule and key... I will try it out myself and confirm... thanks for the respone...

Comment: I must have been having a bad day when I was working on this before... It works perfectly! Thanks...